# Pagination Issue with Expression Engine

Tags: php, pagination, expressionengine

On the backend administration area, I am unable to go to any of the pages of articles via the page number links naturally.

The Page links go to: http://mydomain.com/C=content_edit&tbl_offset=50

But should be going to this: http://mydomain.com/manager.php?D=cp&channel_id=1&C=content_edit&tbl_offset=50

How can this be fixed? Is there a file that needs an edit to it someplace? For some reason it is not picking up the beginning of the URL after the mydomain.com part.

I found a topic that is somewhat similar to mine ( http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/217792/ ), but the fix was specific for Member Sorting, this is not the case in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this issue before (it was a while ago however). It was a known issue with a previous version of EE (sorry I don't have the specific version handy... somewhere between 2.3-2.5 I think). Try upgrading ExpressionEngine and the issue should go away.

If that doesn't work update your answers with the specifics and we might be able to help more.